# Swift 3 - 2D Array of UIView

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a 2D array of UIViews, Everything seems to be working until I try to fill the array with data. I get the error: "fatal error: Index out of range"

What I currently have:

```
var gridArray : [[UIView]] = [[UIView]] ()
```

Now I try to fill the Array with UIViews:

```
for y in 0 ... 10 {
    for x in 0 ... 10 {

        let cell : UIView!
        cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:10, height:10))
        self.view?.addSubview(cell)

        gridArray[x][y] = cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating an array of arrays, but you are not creating the inner arrays.  You can't index into an empty array.  You could create an `11 x 11` array of `UIView?` like this:

```
var gridArray: [[UIView?]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: 11), count: 11)
```

Then your code to fill the array with `UIView`s will work.  You will need to unwrap the `UIView?` when reading it later, but since you fill the array with `UIView`s, this is a case where a force unwrap will work without crashing.

```
let cell = gradArray[x][y]!
```

---

As @rmaddy noted in the comments, you could use a *dummy UIView* to initialize the array:

```
var gridArray: [[UIView]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: UIView(), count: 11), count: 11)
```

This `UIView` would have 121 references to it, and it would be freed by ARC after all of the references to it were replaced by the real `UIView`s.

The advantage is that you'd avoid *optional* `UIView`s, so no unwrapping would be necessary.

Further, you could then drop the type because Swift would be able to infer it:

```
var gridArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: UIView(), count: 11), count: 11)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much

Comment: You can avoid the optional view by filling the inner arrays with a single dummy `UIView` instance that is replaced with the actual view inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy.  I updated my answer to include a discussion of using the dummy `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an Array with the default initializer, the Array is empty, you cannot subscript to an empty Array.

Before accessing the Array with subscript, you need fill in the actual content to the Array:

```
    var gridArray: [[UIView]] = []
    for y in 0 ... 10 {
        var rowArray: [UIView] = []
        for x in 0 ... 10 {

            let cell : UIView!
            cell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:10, height:10))
            self.view?.addSubview(cell)

            rowArray.append(cell)
        }
        gridArray.append(rowArray)
    }
```